# Question about C# covariance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance

In the code below:

```
interface I1 { }
class CI1: I1 { }

List<CI1> listOfCI1 = new List<CI1>();

IEnumerable<I1> enumerableOfI1 = listOfCI1; //this works

IList<I1> listofI1 = listOfCI1; //this does not
```

I am able to assign my "listOfCI1" to an `IEnumerable<I1>` (due to covariance)

But why am I not able to assign it to an `IList<I1>`?
For that matter, I cannot even do the following:

```
List<I1> listOfI12 = listOfCI1;
```

Shouldn't covariance allow me to assign a derived type to a base type?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply put, `IList<T>` is not covariant, whereas `IEnumerable<T>` is. Here's why...

Suppose `IList<T>` *was* covariant. The code below is clearly not type-safe... but where would you want the error to be?

```
IList<Apple> apples = new List<Apple>();
IList<Fruit> fruitBasket = apples;
fruitBasket.Add(new Banana()); // Aargh! Added a Banana to a bunch of Apples!
Apple apple = apples[0]; // This should be okay, but wouldn't be
```

For *lots* of detail on variance, see Eric Lippert's [blog post series](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) on it, or watch the [video](https://vimeo.com/17599365) of my talk about variance from NDC.

Basically, variance is only ever allowed where it's guaranteed to be safe (and in a representation-preserving way, which is why you can't convert `IEnumerable<int>` into `IEnumerable<object>` - the boxing conversion doesn't preserve representation).

Comment: @Arnis: Thank you - I enjoyed it myself, even if I didn't get to show the Hokey Cokey video I'd recorded...

Comment: Jon, so did the BCL team add out (IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable), because IEnumerable does not allow you to add any new members (ie its immutable) making it safe. But on the other hand did not add "out" on IList<T> because it is mutable (making it possible to add a different implementation to the underlying list?)

Comment: @Rajah: That is pretty much correct. Notice how on IEnumerable<T>, every "T" appears in an "output" position, never in an "input" position. Hence "out" for covariance and "in" for contravariance. That's how the compiler and the CLR know that it is safe to be variant. (The actual rules are quite a bit more complicated, but that's a reasonable simplification.)

Comment: @Neme: Done. (Assuming you meant the link to the video.)

Comment: see also: C#'s great big mistake with arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Compare declarations (msdn)

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable

public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

you see that magical word `out`? This means that covariance is on.

Comment: More specifically, it means that `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant *for `T`*. An interface may be variant in some type parameters but not others.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Otherwise, you would then be able add a different implementation of `I1` to a list that should only contain `C1`s.

Answer (score 1):

`IList<T>` interface is not covariant.