# IList<T> vs IEnumerable<T>: Why is this assignment invalid?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Elephant : Animal....

```
IList<Elephant> elephants = new List<Elephant>();
IEnumerable<Animal> animalList = elephants;
```

this works fine but..

```
IList<Elephant> elephants = new List<Elephant>();
IList<Animal> animalList = elephants;
```

throws an error. Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about C# covariance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034495/question-about-c-sharp-covariance)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this

```
IList<Elephant> elephants = new List<Elephant>();
IList<Animal> animalList = elephants;
```

were possible you could then do this

```
animalList.Add(new Animal());
```

but `animalList` is really a reference to the same referrent as `elephants`. And since `elephants` is an `IList<Elephant>` you'd be trying to add an instance of `Animal` to an collection that can only contain instances of `Elephant`.

The reason that it is possible for `IEnumerable<T>` is that `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) in the type parameter `T`. This is because `T` only appears in "out" positions in the interface `IEnumerable<T>`. Since you're only consuming instances of `T` from the `IEnumerable<T>`, it is safe to assign instances of `IEnumerable<Derived>` to variables of type `IEnumerable<Base>`. Anything that comes out of `IEnumerable<Derived>` is a `Base` and this is why something that implements `IEnumerable<Derived>` can be used as a `IEnumerable<Base>` safely. This is why it is safe to assign an instance of `IEnumerable<Elephant>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

But you get in trouble with `IList<T>` because `IList<T>` is not covariant in the type parameter `T`. The issue here is that `T` appears in "in" positions in the interface `IList<T>`. So if you could assign instances of `IList<Derived>` to variables of type `IList<Base>`, then you could try to stick instances of `Base` into the `IList<Base>` which would really be trying to stick instances of `Base` into an instance of `IList<Derived>` and that is clearly not safe to do. This is exactly the issue that we just ran into with `IList<Elephant>` and `IList<Animal>`.

Note that `IList<T>` is also not contravariant in the type parameter `T`. This is because `T` appears in "out" positions in the interface `IList<T>`. If you could assign instances of `IList<Base>` to a variable of type `IList<Derived>` then you could try to grab an instance of `Derived` out of the `IList<Derived>` which would be trying to grab an instance  `Derived` out of an instance of `IList<Base>` and that is clearly absurd.

Comment: Note also that `Derived[]` can be used as `Base[]`, and inserting a `Derived` will throw an exception. This is because .NET inherited the broken Java rules around array variance.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **covariance** and **contravariance**.

I won't go into details but you can [read about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).