# Implementing .Net interfaces (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Probably a simple question.

I have an interface (MyInterface) that defines a property like so:

```
IList<IMenuItem> MenuCollection { get; }
```

And the class implementing MyInterface

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase> MenuCollection 
    {
       get
       {
           ...
       }
    }
    ....
}
```

From what I read, ObservableCollection inherits from a Collection which is a IList, and I have  MenuItemBase class that imlements IMenuItem - wouldn't that satisfy the interface?

I suppose interfaces must be implemented explicitly?

I also tried this:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public IList<IMenuItem> MenuCollection MenuCollection 
    {
       get
       {
           if(_menuCollection == null)
              _menuCollection = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase>();
           return _menuCollection as IList<IMenuItem>;
       }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase> _menuCollection;
}
```

Seems like a workaround hack (and I did run into a few issues saying that MenuCollection was not instantiated) to get the interface to be satisfied.... is there a better way to implement `IInterface1<IInterface2>` objects?

The reason why I need this kind of abstraction is because I'm building a prism / unity app and want to decouple the menu viewmodel as much as possible from the ribbon ui that displays the menu.

Comment: To me, your "workaround hack" feels like the right way to do it...

Comment: Do you even have to cast `_menuCollection` to `IList<IMenuItem>`? If `ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase>` satisfies `IList<IMenuItem>`, you should just be able to return it directly... Shouldn't you?

Comment: Further, I agree with @Stormenet that this isn't really a "hack". You've declared a method to have a generic return type, so its implementation needs a generic return type. This means a caller of the method doesn't need to worry about the concrete internal types used by the method implementation. Looks good to me.

Comment: BTW, your `as` will always return null...

Comment: @djacobson - I tried returning it directly, but it results in a compile time error, my only guess is that it doesnt like returning an ObservableCollection for an IList - I'll have to check the exact error again when I'm back at work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This has nothing to do with generic variance

There are multiple answers talking about *generic* variance. This has nothing to do with the example. If you try to implement a property defined as `IList` with an `ArrayList` (no generics), you will see that it's still not possible to do so.

### The correct answer

This behavior is because if you could implement `MenuCollection` as a property of some type implementing `IList<T>` (or deriving from it, if it were not specified as an interface), then this would be possible:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    IList<IMenuItem> MenuCollection { get; set }
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    // WARNING: Does not count as implementing the interface -- with good reason
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase> MenuCollection { get; set; }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
var classAsInterface = (MyInterface) myClass; // This is OK of course

classAsInterface.MenuCollection = new List<MenuItemBase>(); // OOPS!!
```

In this last line, you have assigned a `List<MenuItemBase>` (which is OK as far as `MyInterface` can tell, since `MyInterface.MenuCollection` is of type `IList<MenuItemBase>`) to a property that is of type `ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase>`.

Of course this is not legal to do, as `List<MenuItemBase>` clearly is not derived from `ObservableCollection<MenuItemBase>`. But it would be a possibility if you could implement the interface like that.

Comment: -1 He doesn't defines a setter in his `MenuCollection` property of his interface, only a getter.

Comment: @Stormenet: Obviously, but the rules of the language cannot change based on whether you define a setter or not.

Answer (score 7):

Jon is correct; this has nothing to do with **generic variance**. However, he does not mention that the feature you are wanting is called **return type covariance**.

That is, if Animal is the base type of Giraffe, then an interface method that returns an Animal, or a virtual method that returns an Animal, may be implemented/specialized by a method that returns a Giraffe. Since every Giraffe is an Animal, the contract is fulfilled.

C# does not support return type covariance; for that matter, neither does the CLR.  Some languages support return type covariance; C++ for example comes to mind.  (The C++/CLI implementation does some sneaky tricks to work around the limitations of the CLR.) The return type of an implemented interface method, the type of a property, and so on, all must match *exactly* in C#.

Comment: These tricks you mention the C++/CLI does might make an interesting read ;)

Comment: @Jon: They're not that sneaky. Just what you'd expect. A bunch of helper methods get generated that are just proxies for the real overloads.

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` and `IList<T>` do not support **covariance**.

See this question: [Question about C# covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034495/question-about-c-covariance)