# Inheritance and return types

Tags: c#, .net

This has been the source of frustration for me for years. It was my understanding that when one class inherits or is otherwise derived from another base class that it could be returned from a method whose signature specifies the base class as it's return value. Since the derivative class MUST, by definition, also be the base class there should be no problem . This is not working for me and has never worked for me so I have always sought work-arounds rather than understand why this is incorrect and what the "correct" solution is.

```
public abstract class Contract
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Id")]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("ContactName")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String ContactName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Column("ContactEmail")]
    public String ContactEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Column("ContactAddress1")]
    public String ContactAddress1 { get; set; }

    ... More properties
}


public class StorageContract : Contract
{

    [DataMember]
    [Column("BoatMaxWidth")]
    public Decimal? BoatMaxWidth { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ColumnAttribute("WidthUOM")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String WidthUOM { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("LaunchDate")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? LaunchDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("TotalCharge")]
    public Decimal? TotalCharge { get; set; }

    ... More properties
}


public class RentalContract : Contract
{
    [DataMember]
    [Column("BoatMake")]
    public String BoatMake { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("BoatYear")]
    public Int32? BoatYear { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("BoatBeam")]
    public Decimal? BoatBeam { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("BoatType")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String BoatType { get; set; }

    ... More properties
}
```

So why would this NOT work ...

```
    public List<Contract> lvContractList_GetData()
    {
        List<Contract> ret = null;
        switch (Request.QueryString["type"].ToLower())
        {
            case "storage":
                ret = ContractRepository2.GetAllContracts<StorageContract>().ToList();
                    break;
            case "rental":
                ret = ContractRepository2.GetAllContracts<RentalContract>().ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

BOTH the StorageContract and RentalContract are derived from the Contract class which makes them ALSO a Contract object.

Why can't I do this?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034495/question-about-c-sharp-covariance/4034509#4034509

Comment: Your confusion is about where the variance is allowed. If I have a function that returns `DerivedType` I can assign the return value to `BaseType` however, a function which who's signature specifies a return type of `BaseType` cannot return `DerivedType` or the return value will not match the method signature causing compiler errors.

Comment: I think that the flaw in your reasoning is considering that all the inherited classes keep the original properties/methods. But they don't have to. For example text1 inherited from TextBox might include a new property called "property1" and text2 also inherited from TextBox might not include this property. Thus, text1 and text2 have quite a few properties in common but not all of them and that's why they cannot be assimilated. Thus, inheritance implies a group of features in common, not all of them.

Comment: @varocarbas - I don't mean to debate as debating is a moot point. It is what it is. Simply to understand. I understand in your example that Text1 and Text2 might not have all the same properties but they both DO contain the properties of the TextBox class they both derive from. So while Text1 != Text2 ... if Text1 == TextBox && Text2 === TextBox then why can't the method just return a TextBox? The calling method can then cast it to whatever specific type they need. Are you suggesting that members of the base class can be modified therefore making them no longer valid TextBox instances?

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom Exactly this is what I suggest. You can have two classes with everything in common and different names and you will not be able to instantiate one by refering to the other. Two persons can be called identically, even think identically but you cannot, for example, sue one person for what other one did. An inherited class is not an instance of the base one, but just takes some of their properties. ToolStrip and MenuStrip are almost identical but you don't try to mix-them up, why you think that will be different with an inherited control?

Comment: debating is a moot point? There is no debate here. You have asked about the reason for something to be in certain way (but, logically, by accepting that you cannot do anything against that) and this is what I have answered. I don't see any "things are like this and end of the discussion", but something which makes plently of sense, at least, by bringing how the language work into picture. Different types/classes have to be treated differently. If the types are supported by a casting/conversion method, this limitation might be overcome. An inherited class/type cannot be supported by...

Comment: Thank you both. I think I am beginning to understand ... not so sure that I like it but I think I understand.

Comment: ... such a casting/conversion method because it wouldn't know how different/similar the two inherited objects are (because of the aforementioned issue of being able to include as many further features as you wish). Even in case of knowing it (impossible), what would do? You have text1 with all the TextBox properties +10 and text2 with all the TextBox properties +25, which would it make with the uncommon properties, etc.

Comment: No problem. Here to help.