# Interface as interface return type

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, interface

In my app I use different web api's for fetching car information. For the services I have implemented ICarService. As all of these Api's return little different set of car data, I have implemented ICar interface, so each services can return their own type of car but in my app I can use "general" ICar.

Here is my implementation:

```
// Car Model
public interface ICar
{
    string Color { get; }
}

public class CarApiA : ICar
{
    public int car_color { get; set; }
    public Color
    {
        get { return this.car_color; }
    }
}


// Service
public interface ICarService
{
    Task<List<ICar>> GetCarsAsync(string search);
}

public class CarApiAService : ICarService
{
    public async Task<List<CarApiA>> GetCarsAsync(string search)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarApiA>>(content);
    }
}
```

Now I get the error message "'CarApiAService' does not implement interface member 'ICarService.GetCarsAsync(string)'. 'CarApiAService.GetCarsAsync(string)' cannot implement 'ICarService.GetCarsAsync(string)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'."

How I use interface to return interface? If this my idea of implementation is completely wrong, please guide me to correct direction.

Comment: Your `Task<List<CarApiA>>` doesn't match the contract in the `ICarService` interface.  That is what the problem is.  Just change it to `Task<list<ICar>>`.  This will work because `CarApiA` *is* an `ICar`.

Comment: did you tried changing the return type of GetCarsAsync to Task<List<ICar>> in CarApiAService ?

Comment: When you specify a generic List, it has to contain only objects of that type - subclasses cannot be used.

Comment: @PugFugly - You can certainly put instances of subtypes into a generic list, but you can't assign a `List<Subclass>` to a `List<Base>`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I did mean assigning the whole list rather than adding indvidual elements. My bad

Comment: If I change the GetCarsAsync return type to Task<List<ICar>> in CarApiAService, I get the error in return line: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CarApiA>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ICar>'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`.  This allows you to use a covariant generic type:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ICar>> GetCarsAsync(string search)
{
    // ...
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarApiA>>(content);
}
```

(Of course the interface also has to be updated…)

```
public interface ICarService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<ICar>> GetCarsAsync(string search);
}
```

---

A word of explanation in case you were wondering about covariance with generic types:

- only a generic interface can be covariant (not generic concrete types like `List<T>`)
- the interface can only be covariant if the generic type is defined as `out` (i.e., read-only).  That's why `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant but `IList<T>` is not

See also Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4034495/1001985), and [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).

Comment: Note, if you are using .NET 4.5 and you need covariance but you also need to get the `.Count` of the collection take a look at [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx)