# IEnumerable<> to List<> Cannot Resolve symbol Add

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface

I am having an issue with classes that implement an interface that has a list of type some other interface.  Tried to create a simple example below.

```
    public interface IPerson
{
    IEnumerable<IPersonEntry> Persons { get; set; }
    DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class PersonType1 : IPerson
{
    public IEnumerable<IPersonEntry> Persons { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public PersonType1()
    {
        Persons = new List<NormalEntry>();
    }
}

public class PersonType2 : IPerson
{
    IEnumerable<IPersonEntry> Persons { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public PersonType2()
    {
        Persons = new List<SomethingDifferent>();
    }
}

public interface IPersonEntry
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NormalEntry : IPersonEntry
{
    // some other props

}

public class SomethingDifferent  : IPersonEntry
{
    // something different
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public SomeMethod()
    {
        PersonType2 p2 = new PersonType2();
        p2.Persons.Add(new SomethingDifferent{
            // blah = 5;
        })

    }
}
```

But in my SomeOtherClass method I want to be able to add to the List but its still getting treated like IEnumerable and not List<>.  So I can't add to it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Defining a property in an `interface` as `public` is not allowed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't add to an `IEnumerable<T>`. Add method is defined in `IList<T>`, so you need to change your parameter type:

```
IList<IPersonEntry> Persons { get; set; }
```

Comment: Alternatively, have the `Add` method in the `PersonType2` class, or cast to `List<IPersonEntry>` in the `SomeOtherClass`.

Comment: Oh nice.  If I change to IList I get an error that I can't convert IList<IPersonEntry> to List<NormalPerson> or whatever it would be.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible that's the classic covariance problem. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034495/question-about-c-sharp-covariance)

Comment: So is there a better approach to this problem then?

Comment: you are trying to violate type-safety. why do you want to add `SomethingDifferent` to a List of type  `NormalEntry` ? if you explain what are you trying to achieve I can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I screwed up my example.  Was doing it from my memory.  What I want to do is create the correct type of person I need depending on some value, probably use Factory here for this.  Then I'll have a method that I will be calling that will be adding the correct type of entries to that newly created person type.  But in the example above I'm adding something different to a list of type something different.  Right?  Person Type 2 has a list of type something different.

Comment: yes it is, sorry I missed it. but the problem is it's type known as `IList<IPersonEntry>` so it migth be storing anything that implements IPersonEntry. that's why compiler doesn't allow you to add `SomethingDifferent`. What I can suggest in this situtation is to make `IPerson` generic and make the property generic as well. and implement it's generic version in your classes. for example in `PersonType1` implement `IPerson<NormalEntry>` .

Comment: Oh wait in PersonTypes I can keep IList<IPersonEntry> but in my method where I want to add things I can just add to the list new objects of whatever type I want right?  This seems to work but seems dangerous that I could try to add anything to the list that implements that interface but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Selman22's answer: The point is that the publicly visible definition of `PersonType2.Persons` is an `IEnumerable`, so it has to be treated like an `IEnumerable` - even if you chose `List` as an implementation for it. And as Selman said, you cannot add to an enumerable.